# Order of elements of the automorphism group is less than the order of the group.

Tags: finite-groups

Let $σ ∈ Aut(G)$, where $G$ is a nonotrivial finite
group. Then show that the order $o(σ)$ of $σ$ is less than $|G|$.

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: This is Horosevskii's theorem, and is not trivial. There is a proof in *Finite Group Theory* by I. Martin Isaacs. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190199/589 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39294/non-trivial-consequences-of-baers-theorem-and-lucchinis-theorem-in-subnormalit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give more detaisl about question and what you have tried. The proof is not so straightforward.
Sketch of the proof;

Let $\Gamma$ be semidirect product of $A=<\sigma>$ and $G$.

**Claim1:** $Core_{\Gamma}(A)=e$.

Notice that $G\cap Core_{\Gamma}(A)=e$ and they are both normal in $\Gamma$. Hence they commutes with each other. But if $e\neq a\in Core_{\Gamma}(A)$ then $a$ commutes with elements of $G$, which means $a$ acts trivially on $G$, which is not possible as $a\in Aut(G)$.

**Theorem:** Let $\Gamma$ be a finite group and $A$ be a cyclic subgroup of $G$. Then $|A:Core(A)|<|{\Gamma}:A|$.

Now, By appliying the theorem, we get $|A|<|G|$.